# winform contols size doesnt work properly

Tags: c#, winforms

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem. The sizing of my winform application works perfect but it doesnt work properly on a different machine. screenshot:
http://s12.postimg.org/9825748b1/samplesizingproblem.png

the controls should fit the whole form.
Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Search for "winforms anchoring" ([click](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/)). When designing app for multiple resolution you have to create dynamic layout. Search for `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` (adding words `c#`, `tutorial`, etc..)

Comment: Can you upload your image to Stack Exchange's imgur account instead of some 3rd party imagehoster. See [this FAQ item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. the (Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display) 
display on the not working windows machine was set at 125%. Replacing it to default 100% was the solution